# Create a tiled image with offset

Tags: php, gd

In the process of creating a tiled image I'd like to set an offset (so that the tile doesn't start at 0, 0) but when I provide what I'd expect to give me the correct image, it's not rendered correctly.

I'm setting the tile using `imagesettile($image, $tile);` but when I go to draw it (using `imagefilledrectangle($image, 10, 10, 300, 300, IMG_COLOR_TILED);`), I get an image as though it was tiled from 0, 0 (with the top & left 10 pixels black) instead of it being tiled from 10, 10.

Any ideas as to how I can get it tiled from 10, 10 or do I have to create another tiled image and copy it across?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I've highlighted the code in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to create a new image which was tiled and copy it in. The final code is along the lines of:

```
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($background_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$tiled_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagefill($tiled_image, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagesettile($tiled_image, $tile);
imagefilledrectangle($tiled_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, IMG_COLOR_TILED);
imagecopyresampled($image, $tiled_image, $sx, $sy, 0, 0, $ex, $ey, $width, $height);
```